# How to gather localhost facts in Ansible while gather_facts is set to "no" for all hosts in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

My playbook uses routers as the hosts to perform tasks on. I have disabled facts for the hosts but I need to get access to `ansible_date_time` from the local host that I'm running the playbook on. The local host is an Ubuntu VM.

This is what my playbook looks like:

```yaml
---
- hosts: lab
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:   
    - name: Run block tasks
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      block:
        - name: Get cert serial number using OpenSSL
          shell: |
            openssl s_client -connect {{ inventory_hostname }}:50051 2>/dev/null  | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p' |openssl x509 -noout -serial  | cut -d'=' -f2 | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'
          register: serialNum
      
        - name: Print Serial Numbers
          debug:
            msg: "{{ serialNum.stdout_lines }}"

    - name: Ansible fact - ansible_date_time
      # gather_facts: yes
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      debug:
        var: ansible_date_time.date
```

I can't put `gather_facts: yes` in the last task since that errors out.

If I enable `gather_facts: yes` at the play level then I get the facts of the routers which is not what I want.

Running the playbook as above gives me the following message:

```
TASK [Ansible fact - ansible_date_time] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [router1.mgt.net] => {
    "ansible_date_time.date": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Is this possible to do with Ansible?

Comment: The problem here is that `delegate_to` does not delegate facts. So `ansible_date_time.date` must be defined for the current host from the `lab` group the task is being ran for. And side note once you know this: delegating a debug task is totally useless: it will run on controller whatever host you delegate to and show vars from the currrent host in play loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I got your use case but here is my take.

Before going further, a few notes.

- Delegating to 127.0.0.1 is globally a bad practice as it might use ssh rather than the `local` connection plugin and force you to define a host in your inventory rather than using the [implicit `localhost`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html)
- We need to gather facts from localhost to get its `ansible_date_time` info. We will do this in a separate play and assign the value as a play var in the next one for ease of use. There are many other ways to deal with this but the bottom line is the use of the [`hostvars` magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) to get a fact from a specific host.
- If you find gathering the full set of facts from localhost is too resource intensive, you can mix my proposition with the one from @β.εηοιτ.βε

Here is how I would fix your playbook (not fully tested)

```yaml
---
- name: Gather facts from localhost for later use
  hosts: localhost
  # If facts gathering is disabled in ansible.cfg you will
  # have to turn it on explicitly (i.e. `gather_facts: true`)
  

- name: Do the actual work on lab routers
  hosts: lab
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    # Get current date from localhost in a play var
    current_date: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.date }}"

  tasks:   
    - name: Get cert serial number using OpenSSL
      shell: |
        openssl s_client -connect {{ inventory_hostname }}:50051 2>/dev/null  | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p' |openssl x509 -noout -serial  | cut -d'=' -f2 | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'
      register: serialNum
      delegate_to: localhost
      
    - name: Print Serial Numbers
      debug:
        msg: "{{ serialNum.stdout_lines }}"

    - name: Show date from localhost gathered at very beginning
      debug:
        var: current_date
```

Comment: The use case is that I need to get the timestamp of a file inside a router and compare it with the current timestamp from the host that I'm running the playbook from. Adding the first task as you recommended did not work. I still get the "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" message when trying to print the "current_date" var.

Comment: My solution above works (tested for gathering and displaying the info from an other host just now). Are you sure you changed your variable to get the info from localhost (i.e `hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.date`)? Meanwhile this will return as I said the timestamp from localhost. Now if you want the timestamp from the target router in the play loop, you have no other choice than gathering facts (at least partially) or to send raw commands in a shell session to get it by yourself.

Comment: My apologies, I had a typo. Yes, your solution does work.

Comment: Feel free to accept (green tick) any of the usefull answer that best suits your need, That will let others know there is a working solution.

Answer (score 4):

The task [`setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) can be used for this. This is actually the task called behind the scene, by Ansible, when you have `gather_facts: yes`.

For this, you don't even need to gather all facts, you can do with a minimal subset of them, with the parameter [`gather_subset`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-gather_subset).

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - setup:
        gather_subset:
          - 'min'
    - debug:
        var: ansible_date_time.date
```

This will yield the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_date_time.date: '2021-07-08'

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to run setup if you need the date only. Simply format [strftime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times). This will give you the current date (and time) without setup, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d'|strftime }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: '2021-07-08'
```

---

Why does it work? It would be very awkward having to run a setup always when the current time is needed, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%H:%M:%S'|strftime }}"
    - wait_for:
        timeout: 3
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%H:%M:%S'|strftime }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: '22:27:07'
  msg: '22:27:11'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a combination of the built-in `date` command and the `ansible.builtin.command` module? For example, I was able to get the date in `YYYY-mm-dd` format using the following playbook:

```yaml
- connection: local
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Get the current date
      ansible.builtin.command: date +%Y-%m-%d
      changed_when: false
      register: date
    - debug:
        var: date.stdout
```

Of course, you can always change the output format of the `date` command.